# "No access hint found for import selector" error occurs when building graalvm native-image to make fat jar for spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Referenced blog : https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/06/spring-boot-graalvm-native-image-maven-plugin/

The following is my application version information

- Spring Boot version : 2.3.3.RELEASE
- spring-graalvm-native version : 0.7.0
- native-image-maven-plugin version : 20.1.0

native-image command

```
time native-image \
  -J-Xmx4G \
  -Dspring.native.verbose=true \
  -H:+TraceClassInitialization \
  -H:Name=$ARTIFACT \
  -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
  -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime \
  -Dspring.graal.missing-selector-hints=warning \
  -Dspring.graal.remove-unused-autoconfig=true \
  -Dspring.graal.remove-yaml-support=true \
  -cp $CP $MAINCLASS;
```

When executed with the above command, the following error occurs.

```
Excluding 2 auto-configurations from spring.factories file
Processing spring.factories - EnableAutoConfiguration lists #7 configurations
Fatal error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No access hint found for import selector: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1005)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:463)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:359)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:518)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No access hint found for import selector: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector
    at org.springframework.graalvm.type.Type.getHints(Type.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.processType(ResourcesHandler.java:900)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.processType(ResourcesHandler.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.processType(ResourcesHandler.java:817)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.checkAndRegisterConfigurationType(ResourcesHandler.java:807)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.processSpringFactory(ResourcesHandler.java:741)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.processSpringFactories(ResourcesHandler.java:578)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.ResourcesHandler.register(ResourcesHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.SpringFeature.beforeAnalysis(SpringFeature.java:78)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$7(NativeImageGenerator.java:679)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:679)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:538)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix it? I ask for help.

Comment: You have native-image-maven-plugin configured but you still run it from your shell? If you want that plugin helps to build native image in your docker with pre-configured graalvm image. Error could be because of local graalvm incompability issue with your project. You can try build it inside the image `mvn -Pnative clean package` after configured the commands/parameters in your plugin